# SUM values using Numbers.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, sum, numbers

I am trying to SUM values from values separated by a dot, like:

[image]

Here is how I am doing this:

```
 computed: {
            total: function(){
                return Number(this.ValorImovelPatrimonio.replace('.','')) + Number(this.ValorAutosPatrimonio.replace('.','')) + Number(this.ValorOutrosPatrimonio.replace('.','')) + Number(this.ValorAcoesPatrimonio.replace('.','')) + Number(this.ValorInvestimentosPatrimonio.replace('.',''));
            },
```

Any hints on how to use it with (or not) Numbers.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Number` you can use `parseInt`, and also use `replace` with the g modifier to replace all ocurrences:

```
 computed: {
        total: function(){
            return parseInt(this.ValorImovelPatrimonio.replace(/\./g,'')) + parseInt(this.ValorAutosPatrimonio.replace(/\./g,'')) + parseInt(this.ValorOutrosPatrimonio.replace(/\./g,'')) + parseInt(this.ValorAcoesPatrimonio.replace(/\./g,'')) + parseInt(this.ValorInvestimentosPatrimonio.replace(/\./g,''));
        },
```